# Quantum chemistry: references

Tags: resource-request, chemistry

I have heard about Quantum chemistry as one of the main applications of quantum computers. However, I have not found concrete related articles with circuit-implementations for these applications.

Does anyone have articles on simulating molecules (such as for instance hydrogen or helium) with a circuit implementation to run it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read [Towards quantum chemistry on a quantum computer](https://www.nature.com/articles/nchem.483) (Nature Chemistry 2010, or here in the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0887))? They present "*a photonic implementation for the smallest problem: obtaining the energies of H$_2$ (the hydrogen molecule) in a minimal basis*". In the figure S1 of the Supporting information there is an equivalence of the operations they implement in circuit notation.